# What is an Inflated Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Inflated Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Inflated Words™ | Not Inflated Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BAYOU | SWAMP |
| DIARY | JOURNAL |
| EASILY | SIMPLY |
| EATERY | DINER |
| FLAY | WHIP |
| FORAY | PILLAGE |
| MAY | APRIL |
| NEATH | UNDER |
| PRAY | IMPLORE |
| SOAPY | SUDSY |
| SOOTY | DIRTY |
| TUSK | HORN |
| WHEY | CURDS |
| SHOYU* | SOY |

*Extra Inflated

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Inflated Words™,Not Inflated Words™
BAYOU,SWAMP
DIARY,JOURNAL
EASILY,SIMPLY
EATERY,DINER
FLAY,WHIP
FORAY,PILLAGE
MAY,APRIL
NEATH,UNDER
PRAY,IMPLORE
SOAPY,SUDSY
SOOTY,DIRTY
TUSK,HORN
WHEY,CURDS
SHOYU,SOY
```

Comment: I think your trademark on 'Word'(TM) and 'Phrase'(TM) is going to cause a lot of havoc!

Comment: @John Those links are meant to refer to the "trademarked phrases" and "trademarked words" puzzle series. However, King.com tried to trademark the word "candy" as it relates to games so maybe JLee should have a go at trademarking "word" and "phrase" as they relate to puzzles. We'll have to go back through and re-tag all the [tag:word] puzzles if that happens.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is:

> If you remove all the vowels from the words (not including Y) they still make a word.

And the extra inflated:

> Even if you remove the Y, it makes a word